# mysql/php - How to implementing a unique view system?

Tags: php, mysql

**Introduction**

I am wondering what is the best way to implement a unique views system... I think I know how, so if I could explain how I think to do it and you point out any mistakes or improvements.

obviously I will have to store a log table containing a video id and something which (relatively) uniquely identifies the user. At first I considered a combination of header request and IP but decided to keep it simple and use just IP. Also that way a user can not increase the views of their video by using a different browser.

**This is how I would think to do it:**

1. When a user visits I do a SELECT
   similar to this:

   `SELECT 1 FROM tbl_log WHERE IP =
   $usersip AND video_id = $video_id`

   - if there is no result then I must
     insert a record

   `INSERT into tbl_log (IP,video_id)
   VALUES ($usersip, $video_id)`

   - and increase the views by 1

   `SELECT views FROM tbl_video WHERE
   video_id = $video_id`

   `UPDATE tbl_video SET views =
   $result['views'] + 1 WHERE video_id
   = $video_id`

**Questions**

- I guess I do not want to have
  millions of log records slowing down 
  my site so should I run a cron job to
  empty the log table once a day?
- Should I make the views
  transactional? (I guess a slightly
  depreciated view count is less
  important than a slow site because of
  row locks)
- Is there a way to reduce the load on 
  the mysql server.... I fear if every 
  view requires an increased view count
  and an IP log that it will be pretty 
  expensive. I have seen that youtube
  and the like do not update the views 
  instantly... do they cache the
  updates some how and then run them at
  once? if so how?
- How efficient is my system? Can you
  think of any improvements?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas for improvements you can make.

Set a primary key on tbl_log to be IP + video_id. Then you can simply do a

```
 REPLACE INTO tbl_log (IP,video_id) VALUES ($usersip, $video_id)
```

(Be sure to escape those php variables to avoid SQL injection.)

Now you're updating your log table with only one query. Next, you can update the views field in tbl_video periodically with something like:

```
UPDATE tbl_video SET views = (select count(*) from tbl_log where video_id = $video_id) where video_id = $video_id
```

You can do that with a cron job, or you can add a 'last_count_update' field and update the video when it is accessed if the last count time is older than 2 hours or whatever. This will be a little less work if you have a bunch of videos that aren't visited often.

Comment: Both your suggestions make a lot of sense, only problem I see with the second one is that it does not clear the log... so every time it is executed it will count the results regardless of if they have already been counted. I guess I have two options... have the life of the log equal to when the views update (by having the log emptied when the views are counted) OR by adding a counted field to stop a log being counted multiple times. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it counts the results regardless of whether they've been counted. But it doesn't ADD that count to the existing count - it replaces the existing count.

Comment: I don't see any way to guarantee unique views if you're clearing the log table. You'll either have to live with a big table or change your definition of unique. If, for example, you decide that unique means per IP and per day or week, then you can clear the table of any records from the previous day/week (or older) after you count them. But then you would have to deal with adding them rather than replacing the count. Then you would need something like the counted field you mentioned.

Comment: true... but do I really want eternal records to ensure unique views? Surely every day that goes by the check to see if the user has visited before and the count would take longer and longer to execute?

Comment: In my eyes, the unique view is less about counting individual people (which as many users are behind a router at work/school is incorrect anyway) and more about stopping people repeatedly pressing refresh to increase their view count....

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I do not want to have
>   millions of log records slowing down my site so should I run a cron
>   job to empty the log table once a day?

Consider using mysql's ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE syntax to avoid using a SELECT which would have an expensive WHERE clause.  If your log table also had a timestamp column, you could refresh that value.

```
INSERT into tbl_log (IP,video_id) VALUES ($usersip, $video_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE time_recorded = now();
```

This would require you to have a UNIQUE constraint on the `IP` and `video_id` columns.

> Should I make the views transactional?
>   (I guess a slightly depreciated view
>   count is less important than a slow
>   site because of row locks)

No, because you can achieve this with a single UDPATE query.

```
UPDATE tbl_video SET views = views + 1 WHERE video_id = $video_id
```

> Is there a way to reduce the load on
>   the mysql server.... I fear if every
>   view requires an increased view count
>   and an IP log that it will be pretty
>   expensive. I have seen that youtube
>   and the like do not update the views
>   instantly... do they cache the updates
>   some how and then run them at once? if
>   so how?

It's not too bad - there's really no other way to reliably capture record-view data.  In the case of Youtube, it's more likely delayed writes or replication that's causing the delay you notice since they have hundreds of servers (although it's possible they are caching the value as well)

> How efficient is my system? Can you
>   think of any improvements?

Other than what I mentioned here already, not off the top of my head.

Comment: sorry I do not understand your first suggestion... how does having an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE mean I do not have to empty the log? Do you mean it will be faster to execute the SQL because there is no WHERE and thus I do not have to empty the log?